# Discord.js send message to specific channel and react to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I know you can do something like this:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch("Channel id");
  channel.send('Message');
```

But what if I wanted to react to the message I sent? You need the message object to react right?

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextChannel#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message)>.
You'll have to await the message to be sent to be able to react to it.

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('Channel id');
const message = await channel.send('Message');
await message.react('');
console.log('Reacted to message.');
```